# How to filter a JS array based on user input in such a way that user writes "Brl", and it shows Berlin (letters aren't one after another immediately)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of cities
`var cities = ['Berlin', 'Bucharest', 'Paris', 'Munich', 'Amsterdam', 'Milan'];`
This array needs to be filtered based on the search input passed (f.e., user inputs **'m'**, and it shows **'Munich', 'Amsterdam', and 'Milan'**, then the user adds 'a' to 'm' in search input (writes **'ma'**), and it shows him **"Amsterdam' and 'Milan'**, although these letters are not one immediately after another). Moreover, I then need these letters to be highlighted in some way, so, let's say, letters 'm' & 'a' in these words are yellow.

This is what I've done so far, but it doesn't work as I need.

```
var input = document.querySelector("input").value.toLowerCase().trim();
document.addEventListener('input', search)

function search() {
 var filteredArray = cities.filter(x => x.toLowerCase().includes(input));
 console.log(filteredArray);//to see what I've got
}
```

Appreciate any help! I'm new to JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: You can do the filtering by turning the input into a regular expression, e.g. `brl` becomes `/b.*r.*l/`. Highlighting the matching letters is harder.

Comment: You forgot to pass input value to search function.

Comment: It's logic, not JavaScript. Basically, you need break up `input` into its letters, then find out if all of those letters are in each of the cities.

Comment: @HereticMonkey They also have to be in the right order.

Comment: ... @Heretic, and also check if the indexes are in the same order. Gets complex (and possibly slow), fast. Using regexp is the way to go here.

Comment: Where, in the question, does it say they have to be in the right order?

Comment: It's implied by the request that `brl` should find `Berlin`. Arguably `Liberacion` shouldn't pop when typing `brl`. Only when typing `lbr`. At least, that's my first impulse, (besides asking for more exact specs, that is).

Comment: Is this an exercise or do you just want it to work? If the latter you can look at [`fuse.js`](https://fusejs.io/) for fuzzy search

Answer (score 0):

You might filter like this.

```js
document.addEventListener('input', search);

const cities = ['Berlin', 'Bucharest', 'Paris', 'Munich', 'Amsterdam', 'Milan'];

function search(e) {
  const input = e.target.value.toLowerCase().trim();
  const filteredArray = cities.filter(x => {
    const c = x.toLowerCase();
    let m = 0;
    for (let l of input) {
      const i = c.substr(m).indexOf(l);
      if (i < m) return false;
      m = i;
    }
    return true;
 });
 console.log(filteredArray);//to see what I've got
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Also, you might remember indexes to highlight matching letters.